# Is it possible to make "shortcut icon" round using css?

Tags: html, css, border

Maybe it will sound stupid, i really dont know much, but is it possible to style 
shortcut icon with for example border-radius to make it round? Or it have to be done before in such a programs for that? Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean favicon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to favicons, you cannot round the corners using CSS. CSS can only target elements that exist within the DOM.

You can use programs like [Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html) (paid) or [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) (free) to apply rounding.

Answer (score 0):

No, shortcut icon is not a DOM html element to style with css; it is just a external resource of the document tree.

Answer (score 0):

as they said it is external resource of the document tree.
you can use [crop-circle](https://crop-circle.imageonline.co/) to make it rounded in less than 30s .