# Is there a way to change the border radius of a favicon icon?

Tags: html, css, favicon

I have a square favicon icon, but I'd like to resize it on the browser head, I tried to create a class on the head of the index but i can't edit it on the css.

```
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" class="icon">
```

Comment: I want to change the border/radius

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make "shortcut icon" round using css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821291/is-it-possible-to-make-shortcut-icon-round-using-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no way to apply CSS in a favicon.
you need to use a program to do this

Comment: You are welcome, you can accept the answer so people can find it easily. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.

Comment: do you have a recommended one or have had good experiences with any?